# Jquery UI menu weird behaviour

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, menu

I have a problem using Jquery UI Menu plugin in my MVC 4 application.

I have a simple html with empty  element inside of it that is supposed to get populated ot document.ready event. Well, this happens but the html looks weird after it comes back from the ajax. Before returning it and trying to set it via `$("#myUl").html(valueFromTheAjax)` I `console.log()` it.

When the  `$("#myUl").html(valueFromTheAjax)` is applied the html looks weird(like a broken css) but when I copy the value from the console and paste it in the html by hand everything is perfect.

Here is my html:

```
<div id="categories-menu-wrapper" style="width:203px; height:300px; border:2px solid; float:left">
  <ul id="menutomi" class="ui-menu" style="width:200px;height:auto;">


  </ul>
</div>
<div id="preview-wrapper" style="width: 100%; height: 300px; border: 2px solid;">
</div>
```

And this is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:49833/api/Categories",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            crossOrigin: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#menutomi").append(UXManagement.LoadAllCategories(data));
            },
            error: function (e) {
                alert("Error");
                alert(JSON.stringify(e));
            }
        })
    })
```

and the html formatting:

```
UXManagement.CategoriItemTemplate = "<li><a class=\"delete-cat\" data=\"http://localhost:49833/api/Categories?categoryId={{CAT_ID}}\"><img title=\"Delete category\" src=\"Content/Images/delete-icon.png\"/></a><a class=\"add-product\" data=\"http://localhost:49833/api/Products?categoryId={{CAT_ID}}\"><img title=\"Add product\" src=\"Content/Images/add-new-icon.jpg\" /></a>{{CATEGORY_TITLE}}<ul>{{NESTED_UL}}</ul></li>";
    UXManagement.ProductItemTemplate = "<li><a class=\"delete-product\" data=\"http://localhost:49833/api/Products?productId={{PROD_ID}}&categoryId={{CAT_ID}}\"><img title=\"Delete Product\" src=\"Content/Images/delete-icon.png\" /></a><a class=\"product-item\" data=\"http://localhost:49833/api/Products/ProductById/{{PROD_ID}}\">{{PRODUCT_NAME}}</a></li>";

UXManagement.LoadAllCategories      = function (data) {

        var categoryHtml = [];

        $.each(data, function (i, elem) {

            var productsHtml            = [];
            $.each(elem["Products"], function (i, product) {
                var replaceValue = UXManagement.ProductItemTemplate.replace(/{{PROD_ID}}/g, product["Identifier"])
                                                                    .replace(/{{CAT_ID}}/g, elem["Id"])
                                                                    .replace(/{{PRODUCT_NAME}}/g, product["Name"]);

                productsHtml.push(replaceValue);
            })

            var wholeReplaceInCategory  = UXManagement.CategoriItemTemplate.replace(/{{CAT_ID}}/g, elem["Id"])
                                                                    .replace(/{{CATEGORY_TITLE}}/g, elem["Name"])
                                                                    .replace(/{{NESTED_UL}}/g, productsHtml.join(""));

            categoryHtml.push(wholeReplaceInCategory);
        })


        console.log(categoryHtml.join(""));
        return categoryHtml.join("");
    }
```

It would be great if someone could help because I find it really hard to handle it. Thank you!

**EDIT:**

[image: When dynamically set html($("#myUl").html())]

[image: When copy-pasted from the console]

Comment: What do you mean by 'looks weird' ?Can you show us a picture?

Comment: @VaMoose Yes of course. I am going to show you. I will update my question